# RedirectToAction to multiple HttpPost Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, redirecttoaction

I created a button that directs to another page with 3 tabs.

These 3 subtabs has different input text and only using 1 Action [HttpGet].

These are my cases.

1. I want to save only first tab data, the 2 tabs value will be null
2. I want to save only second data, the 1st tab and 3rd tab will be null
3. I want to save all the text input that I've typed under 1st tab, 2nd tab, and 3rd tab.

Here is my code:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create_Data(int productId)
 {
      var model = BigViewModel();
      ///rest of code
      return View(model)
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create_Data(BigViewModel model, int productId)
 {
      int experimentForOverloading = 0;
      string experimentAgain = ""

      // validates if first tab and doesn't have data inputted, will redirect to Create_SecondTab. Below is just for testing
      if (model.FirstTabName == null && model.ThirdTabDirectory == null)
      {

           // this is where I want to go to route the new Action. But I don't know what to do..
           return RedirectToAction("CreateData", new
           {
                model = BigViewModel,
                Id = productId,
                experimentForOverloading
           }
      }
      else if (model.SecondTabSalary == null && model.ThirdTabDirectory == null)
      {
           return RedirectToAction("CreateData", new
           {
                model = BigViewModel,
                Id = productid
                experimentAgain
           }
      }
      else
      {
           return RandomView(); //Testing purposes
      }
 }

 // This is the second case, save only when first tab is empty
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateData(BigViewModel, int bigId, int experimentForOverloading)
 {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           //.. code here
           _context.SaveChanges()
      }
      else
      {
           return RandomView(); //Testing purpose
      }
 }

 // This is the first case, save only when second and third tab is empty
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult CreateData(BigViewModel, int bigId, string experimentAgain)
 {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           //.. code here
           _context.SaveChanges()
      }
      else
      {
           return RandomView(); //Testing purpose
      }
 }
```

Comment: You can't redirect to a POST. Web browsers don't handle that reliably.

Comment: The MVC follows PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern for redirection schema. After a POST request, you should use `RedirectToAction` to redirect into a controller which uses GET method to show another page.